# Circular Linked List - Count Number of Nodes

Tags: linked-list, circular-list

I am trying to find an algorithm to count the number of nodes in a Circular linked list by using **one pointer only**.

Does anyone know any algorithm?

Comment: It's easy with two pointers, but one sounds like it is impossible.

Comment: This is a task I got, it is required to use one pointer only.

Comment: Where did you get this task from?

Comment: I got it from university

Comment: You know the head of the pointer, just use a single pointer and a counter to traverse the list until you reach the head again.

Comment: It is a solution with two pointers, one to the head the second iterates the list - it is no good

Comment: The head is a known pointer you don't move, and you only move one pointer

Comment: This is the trivial solution. And still it is a 2 pointers solution and not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try checking this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-nodes-circular-linked-list/
2. We can also use array to keep count of the nodes visited and exit one's the node count becomes 2. But this approach works for linked list with unique elements only.